# Custom Taxonomy Not Saving in Front End Post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, forms, front-end

I am trying to create a front end posting form that will allow users to create a post when schools are closed. I have 4 custom taxonomies closed_schools, study_open, safe_arrival, hour_delay. each has the same list of 30 or so schools. Once the post is submitted I want to display the schools that are closed, opened, delayed etc.

If I build the post in the back end it works, and shows everything like I intend. If I post from the front end none of the categories show up, So I know there is something wrong with how I am storing the taxonomies but I have tried many forums and techniques but no luck. Any help would be super appreciated, thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $category = $_POST['cat'];
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
    $terms = $_POST['terms'];

$error_msg = array();
if($title == ''){
    $error_msg[] = 'Please select an area and/or region.';
}
if($description == ''){
    $error_msg[] = 'Please write a description for the closure and/or delay.';
}
if($category == '-1'){
    $error_msg[] = 'Please identify the reason for the closure and/or delay.';
}
else if( !$error_msg && 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post"){
    $new_post = array(
    'post_title'    =>  $title,
    'post_content'  =>  $description,
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
    'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
    'tax_input' => array(terms),
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' =>  'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);

//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

//SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY
wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

//SET OUR POST TERMS, CUSTOM TAXONOMIES
wp_set_post_terms($pid, $_POST['terms'], 'closed_schools', 'safe_open', 'safe_arrival', 'hour_delay', true);

//REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVEs
$link = get_permalink( $pid );
wp_redirect( $link );
//POST THE POST
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
}

}
```

My Form Istelf

```
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" class="wpcf7-form front-end-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- post name -->
    <fieldset name="name">
        <label for="title" class="selection-title">Area and/or Region:</label>
        <!--<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="5" name="title" />-->
        <select name="title" id="title">
            <option value="">-Please select an area and/or region-</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- post Category -->
    <fieldset class="category">
        <label for="cat" class="selection-title">Reason For closure and/or delay:</label>
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => 'cat', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $category->parent, 'hierarchical' => true, 'show_option_none' => __('Select an area and/or region'))); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- post Content -->

     <fieldset>
     <label for="closed_schools" class="selection-title">Closed Schools:</label>
     <?php
        $closed_schools = get_terms('closed_schools', 'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($closed_schools as $close) {
        $counter++;
        $option = '<label for="'.$close->slug.'">'.$close->name.'</label>';
        $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="terms[]" id="'.$close->slug.'" value="'.$close->slug.'">';
        echo $option;
       }
                    ?>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
      <label for="study_open" class="selection-title">Open for Study Only:</label>
      <?php
        $study_only = get_terms('study_open', 'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($study_only as $study) {
            $counter++;
            $option = '<label for="'.$study->slug.'">'.$study->name.'</label>';
        $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="terms[]" id="'.$study->slug.'" value="'.$study->slug.'">';
        echo $option;
        }
    ?>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
       <label for="open_for_safe_arrival" class="selection-title">Open for Safe Arrivals Only:</label>
       <?php
        $safe_arrival = get_terms('safe_arrival', 'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($safe_arrival as $safe) {
            $counter++;
            $option = '<label for="'.$safe->slug.'">'.$safe->name.'</label>';
            $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="terms[]" id="'.$safe->slug.'" value="'.$safe->slug.'">';
            echo $option;
        }
        ?>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
          <label for="2_hour_delay" class="selection-title">2 Hour Delay:</label>
          <?php
            $hour_delay = get_terms('hour_delay', 'orderby=id&hide_empty=0');
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($hour_delay as $delay) {
            $counter++;
            $option = '<label for="'.$delay->slug.'">'.$delay->name.'</label>';
            $option .= '<input type="checkbox" name="terms[]" id="'.$delay->slug.'" value="'.$delay->slug.'">';
            echo $option;
        }
        ?>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset class="content">
        <label for="description" class="selection-title">Description and Notes:</label>
        <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="submit">
            <button type="submit" value="Submit Cancellation/Closure" name="submit" tabindex="40" id="submit"><span>Submit Cancellation/Closure</span></button>
            <!--<input type="submit" value="Submit Cancellation/Closure" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit" />-->
        </fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after much trial and error. Made some slight changes to the $new_post array.

```
else if( !$error_msg && 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post"){
        $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    =>  $title,
        'post_content'  =>  $description,
        'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
        'tax_input' => array('closed_schools' => $_POST['terms'], 'study_open' => $_POST['terms'], 'safe_arrival' => $_POST['safe_arrival'], 'hour_delay' => $_POST['hour_delay']), //Place all of our custom taxonomies into the posted variable terms as an array
        'post_status'   =>  'publish', // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' =>  'post',  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );
```

Also to use wp_set_object_terms instead of wp_set_post_terms on each custom taxonomy

```
//SET OUR POST TERMS, CUSTOM TAXONOMIES
wp_set_object_terms($pid, $_POST['terms'], 'closed_schools');
wp_set_object_terms($pid, $_POST['terms'], 'study_open');
wp_set_object_terms($pid, $_POST['terms'], 'safe_arrival');
wp_set_object_terms($pid, $_POST['terms'], 'hour_delay');
```

Comment: note that `tax_input` only works if the user submitting the post has the capability to modify that taxonomy.